# Extracting information by scraping products

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm learning how to take information of products by scraping ecommerce and I have achieved a little, but there are parts that I'm not able of parse.

With this code I can take the information that is in the labels

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup('A LOT OF HTML HERE', 'html.parser')
productos = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'item product product-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4'})
for product_info in productos:

  # To store the information to a dictionary
  web_content_dict = {}
  web_content_dict['Marca'] = product_info.find('div',{'class':'product-item-manufacturer'}).text
  web_content_dict['Producto'] = product_info.find('strong',{'class':'product name product-item-name'}).text
  web_content_dict['Precio'] = product_info.find('span',{'class':'price'}).text


  
  # To store the dictionary to into a list
  web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)
df_kiwoko = pd.DataFrame(web_content_list)
```

I can take information from for example:

```
<div class="product-item-manufacturer"> PEDIGREE </div>
```

And I'd like to take information from this part:

```
<a href="https://www.kiwoko.com/sobre-pedigree-pollo-en-salsa-100-g-pollo- 
y-verduras.html" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1" 
data-id="PED321441" data-name="Sobre Pedigree Vital Protection pollo y 
verduras en salsa 100 g" data-price="0.49" data-category="PERROS" data- 
list="PERROS" data-brand="PEDIGREE" data-quantity="1" data-click=""
```

For example take "Perros" from

```
data-category="PERROS"
```

How can I take information from parts that are not between >< and take the elements between ""?

Comment: Can you post the initial url?

Comment: https://www.kiwoko.com/tienda-de-perros-online.html this is the initial url

Comment: you want to extract the attribute value. This has come up before so worth looking at questions and answers already given on SO (otherwise we get a lot of duplicates) E.g. soup.select_one("[data-category]")['data-category']

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors  and  https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#attributes